# emulating method type parameters in generic go

Tags: go, generics, functor

After watching Philip Wadler's talk on featherweight go I was really excited about the newest [go generics draft](https://blog.golang.org/generics-next-step). But now with a version of the new generics draft available for us to play with it seems some of the things from featherweight go are no longer possible. In the both the [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dq0WFigax_c), and the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.11710) he introduces a functor like interface called `List`. The approach from the paper doesn't quite work.

```
type Any interface {}

type Function(type a Any, b Any) interface {
    Apply(x a) b
}

type Functor interface {
   Map(f Function) Functor
}
```

fails with the error: `cannot use generic type Function(type a, b) without instantiation`

and if you try to add type parameters to the method, and use a normal function you get: `methods cannot have type parameters`

I'm wonder if anyone has found an approach to making functors work with the current version of the draft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't carried the generic types through; in your example code, `Functor` is treating `Function` as if it were not generic. The correct code (which compiles, [see here](https://go2goplay.golang.org/p/gQuuM0zMBjZ)) would be:

```
type Function(type a Any, b Any) interface {
    Apply(x a) b
}

type Functor(type a Any, b Any) interface {
   Map(f Function(a,b)) Functor(a,b)
}
```

Comment: This isn't satisfactory, though, as you'd really want the second type parameter to be attached to the `Map` method rather than to the `Functor` type. This limitation persists in the latest draft (https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/go2draft-type-parameters.md).

Comment: The Functor type is an interface which defines only the Map method, so it makes absolutely no difference.

Comment: It makes a huge difference to me.

Comment: @jub0bs then post your own question relating your own case and I'd be happy to take a look, because in the case of this question, it does not make any difference.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to hijack the comment section. There's no question that I need answered: the draft proposal says it all. The restriction I mentioned is unfortunate and does matter, because [a functor normally takes one parameter, not two](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor). See how Phil Wadler defines his `List` interface type in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dq0WFigax_c&t=38m30s. Sadly, the current draft proposal doesn't allow that, and [Phil's code doesn't compile in the go2goplayground](https://go2goplay.golang.org/p/HKoceijRaGj).

Comment: If `a` and `b` are the same type, then only one type parameter is required. If they are different types, then there are two type parameters. An interface in Go *must* define a compile-time static type, which means that any type parameters used in methods defined in the interface must be defined on the interface itself, otherwise the interface would be unusable in practice.

Comment: A functor's map functionality requires the two type parameters to possibly be different. As for the rest of your comment, this section of the draft proposal offers a more nuanced view: https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/go2draft-type-parameters.md#No-parameterized-methods